# How do I access machines on the home network with their machine name?

Tags: networking, avahi

I have all machines connecting to the internet through a wireless router (occasionally I plug a machine into the router via cable). I have installed the ssh package and can access one Ubuntu machine from another using, for example, "ssh 10.0.0.2". However, the local IP addresses change as machines are switched off and on and reconnect to the router, so I'd prefer to use "ssh machinename".

If I do type "ssh machinename", nothing happens, no error, no returning to the prompt.

What do I need to install/configure to access Ubuntu machines via their machine name?

(As a side note, I have Samba installed so I can access Windows machines on the same network. I have set [name resolve order = lmhosts wins bcast host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22376/how-can-i-access-windows-shares-after-changing-dns-servers-e-g-switching-to-ope/22377#22377) because I use OpenDNS, I'm not sure if this could affect Ubuntu networking. Name-based resolution works in both directions between Windows and Ubuntu (for example, connecting to an Ubuntu machine with WinSCP).)

Comment: The simple way: use static addresses, and put them in /etc/hosts of each machine.

Comment: enzotib: how do I "use static addresses"? would I need to configure something on the router? I found another answer relating to avahi which worked for me, is it possible this is doing what you describe automatically? feel free to add your answer to the mix :)

Comment: The other answer is ok, so I don't elaborate anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access server by host name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2631/access-server-by-host-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make sure you have the Avahi daemon installed. (Should be installed by default on Ubuntu Desktop, but not on Server.)

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

Then to access them, add ".local" to the end of the name, for example

```
ssh machinename.local
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to remove the need to add .local

Comment: based on this answer and comments http://askubuntu.com/questions/2631/access-ubuntu-server-by-host-name/2632#2632

Comment: I don't know how I had managed to miss that, but thank you very much! That makes things much easier for me :)

Comment: It is not installed on debian by default, so keep this in mind if you ever use debian ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to ssh into a machine by using a good to remember name you can also define a name in `~/.ssh/config` by adding an entry like e.g.:

```
Host myremote
    HostName 192.168.0.0 # IP or myremote.local name of remote
    Port 980 # Port to connect if different to defaults
    User <myloginname>
```

We are then able to ssh to *myremote.local* by simply typing:

```
ssh myremote
```